# Are obsolete documentation topics allowed?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics, documentation-examples

I came across this topic on Stack Overflow Documentation:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/5212/deprecated-and-obsolete-features

It got deleted later on. Part of the deletion notice said:

> *This may have been done for any number of reasons **: obsolescence,** consolidation, reorganization, etc.*

Note that obsolescence is one of the possible reasons it could've been deleted. Was the topic deleted for obsolescence, or was it deleted for something else? If it was indeed deleted for obsolescence, that'd mean obsolete topics are not allowed on Documentation.

Are obsolete Documentation topics allowed?

Examples of "obsolete" topics include:

- Internet Explorer 6 compatibility
- Deprecated and obsolete features in [programming language]
- Python 1.0, Java 1.0, etc.

---

**EDIT 1:** I mean Documentation topics that are supposed to be about obsolete things, not obsolete examples for topics covering newer technologies.

---

**EDIT 2:** [One of my proposed topics](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/79688?draftId=66556) was rejected because obsolete HTML elements were considered "useless information."

Comment: Yes, let's add a "Netscape Navigator compatibility" section.

Comment: Ie6 compatibility is not obsolete for people who still have to support ie6 installs. Deprecated features in a language aren't obsolete for people still using that version of the language.

Comment: I consider a list topic, like "Deprecated and Obsolete Features" to be useless. If, under a specific feature, one wants to use the version comments to mark an *example* as pertaining to a deprecated version, that's fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's referring to a different type of obsolete Documentation. The other two terms clearly refer to organizational changes.

That leads me to believe that it refers to any situation where the same content (but better) exists elsewhere. Meaning it is obsolete due to the fact that a better Example covering the same content was published or discovered.

If they didn't want Documentation to cover old examples, we wouldn't have versions, and we certainly wouldn't have the `[lte old_ver]` syntax.